# VS 2015 vs. 2017 javascript intellisense (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, javascript-intellisense

I have tested Javascript Intellisense in both Visual Studio 2015 Community and in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. The former it's neither context-aware, nor it contains method or argument descriptions.

As an example, the following prompt the Intellisense suggestion only in 2017 (please refer also to the screenshots):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/d3.js"></script>
    <script>
        d3.line
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[VS 2017 js intellisense working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2fTw.png)

[VS 2015 js intellisense not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAF2D.png)

I work at a company where we have VS2015 for other reasons.
Any workaround is appreciated.